# Why fit_round received failures in flwr framework?

Tags: python, pytorch, federated-learning

I am using flwr framework to send a random array from client to server and then server will merge the array and sends back to each of the clients.

```
import numpy as np
import flwr as fl
from flwr.server.strategy import Strategy 
from typing import List

class MergeArraysStrategy(fl.server.strategy.FedAvg): 
     
    def aggregate_fit(self, rnd, results, failures):
        
        aggregated_parameters, aggregated_metrics = super().aggregate_fit(rnd, results, failures)
        print(aggregated_parameters, aggregated_metrics)
        # if aggregated_parameters is not None:
        #     # Convert `Parameters` to `List[np.ndarray]`
        #     aggregated_ndarrays: List[np.ndarray] = fl.common.parameters_to_ndarrays(aggregated_parameters)

        #     # Save aggregated_ndarrays
        #     print(f"Saving round {rnd} aggregated_ndarrays...")
        #     np.savez(f"round-{rnd}-weights.npz", *aggregated_ndarrays)

        # return aggregated_parameters, aggregated_metrics
        print(results)
        self.arrays = []
        for result in results:
            self.arrays.append(result.parameters)

        if self.arrays:
            merged_array = np.concatenate(self.arrays)
            self.arrays = []
            return merged_array, {} 
        else:
            # Return some default or empty array if there are no results
            return np.array([]), {} 
        
    def configure_evaluate(self, server_round, parameters, client_manager):
        pass

    def evaluate(self, value, parameters):
        pass


# Create a Flower server
strategy = MergeArraysStrategy(min_available_clients=3, min_fit_clients=3)
client_manager = fl.server.SimpleClientManager()
server = fl.server.Server(client_manager=client_manager, strategy=strategy)

# Start the server
fl.server.start_server(
    server_address="127.0.0.1:8080",
    config=fl.server.ServerConfig(num_rounds=2),
    server=server
)
```

Client code:

```
 import flwr as fl
import numpy as np
import flwr   

from flwr.common import (
    Code,
    EvaluateIns,
    EvaluateRes,
    FitIns,
    FitRes,
    GetParametersIns,
    GetParametersRes,
    Status,
    ndarrays_to_parameters,
    parameters_to_ndarrays,
)

class Client(fl.client.NumPyClient):

    def __init__(self, array):
        self.array = array 
        print(self.array)
    
    def get_parameters(self, ins: GetParametersIns) -> GetParametersRes:
        #print(f"[Client {self.cid}] get_parameters")

        # Get parameters as a list of NumPy ndarray's
        ndarrays: np.ndarray  = self.array

        # Serialize ndarray's into a Parameters object
        parameters = ndarrays_to_parameters(ndarrays)

        # Build and return response
        status = Status(code=Code.EVALUATE_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, message="Success")
        return GetParametersRes(
            status=status,
            parameters=parameters,
        )

    # def fit(self, parameters):
    #     self.array = parameters
    #     fit_res = flwr.common.FitRes(status=flwr.common.Status(
    #             code=flwr.common.Code.EVALUATE_NOT_IMPLEMENTED ,
    #             message="Client does not implement `fit`",
    #         ),
    #         parameters=self.array,
    #         num_examples=len(self.array ),
    #         metrics={})
    #     return fit_res
    
    def fit(self, ins: FitIns) -> FitRes:
        # Deserialize parameters to NumPy ndarray's
        parameters_original = ins.parameters
        self.array = parameters_to_ndarrays(parameters_original)

        # Update the model parameters using your training logic
        # This is where you should perform the model training with the received parameters

        # Serialize updated ndarray's into a Parameters object
        parameters_updated = ndarrays_to_parameters(self.array)

        # Build and return response
        status = Status(code=Code.EVALUATE_NOT_IMPLEMENTED, message="Success")  # Change the status code to SUCCESS
        return FitRes(
            status=status,
            parameters=parameters_updated,  # Return the updated model parameters
            num_examples=len(self.array),
            metrics={},
        )
    
    def evaluate(self, parameters):
        pass
 
# Create a Flower client
client = Client(array=np.random.randn(2))

# Connect to the server
fl.client.start_client(server_address="127.0.0.1:8080", client=client)

# The server should handle the aggregation logic and return the merged array
# The client can retrieve the merged array from its 'array' attribute
merged_array = client.array
print(merged_array)
```

**Scenario:**
Suppose two clients have [1, 2] and [3, 4] data. The server will collect these datasets and concatenate them. Then the server will have [1, 2, 3, 4] and send back to each of the clients. So after one round each client will have [1, 2, 3, 4].

But I am getting the result as my expectation. The error log on the server side is as follows:

```
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:29,709 | app.py:165 | Starting Flower server, config: ServerConfig(num_rounds=2, round_timeout=None)
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:29,745 | app.py:179 | Flower ECE: gRPC server running (2 rounds), SSL is disabled
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:29,746 | server.py:89 | Initializing global parameters
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:29,746 | server.py:277 | Requesting initial parameters from one random client     
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:37,053 | server.py:281 | Received initial parameters from one random client
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:37,054 | server.py:91 | Evaluating initial parameters
None
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:37,054 | server.py:105 | FL starting
DEBUG flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,744 | server.py:228 | fit_round 1: strategy sampled 3 clients (out of 3)
DEBUG flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,759 | server.py:242 | fit_round 1 received 0 results and 3 failures
None {}
[]
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,760 | server.py:172 | evaluate_round 1: no clients selected, cancel
DEBUG flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,760 | server.py:228 | fit_round 2: strategy sampled 3 clients (out of 3)      
DEBUG flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,766 | server.py:242 | fit_round 2 received 0 results and 3 failures
None {}
[]
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,766 | server.py:172 | evaluate_round 2: no clients selected, cancel
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,767 | server.py:154 | FL finished in 10.712144899999998
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,767 | app.py:225 | app_fit: losses_distributed []
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,768 | app.py:226 | app_fit: metrics_distributed_fit {}
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,768 | app.py:227 | app_fit: metrics_distributed {}
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,768 | app.py:228 | app_fit: losses_centralized []
INFO flwr 2023-10-27 18:55:47,769 | app.py:229 | app_fit: metrics_centralized {}
```